# Getting extent of raster in ArcMap to 12 decimal places

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, extents

I have a raster file in arcmap and want to get the extent of the raster to 12 decimal places, the extent in properties gives 9 places.

Does anyone know how I can increase it?

Comment: Why? https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/2170:_Coordinate_Precision

Comment: haha fair, was requested as part of a config but I will now find out why such precision